# How to place small image on centre of webview background

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

Am trying to place a small image on the centre of my WebView so when webview doesn't load any content the image will be visible. The problem is that the image take the full width and height of the webview, I have tried many things to place it on the centre but none of it worked. And my last attempt doesn't allow the app to lunch.

Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/AppId">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wbg_icon);
    webview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
    relativeLayout.addView(webview, layoutParams);
```

Comment: use frame layout

Comment: @HussainAbbas frame layout is okay, but I want something that will be hidden as soon as the content start loading, or is there a way to make the image stay below WebViews content?

Comment: you can set its visibility gone

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/AppId">
    </WebView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The image is placed on top of webview, how do I have it once once WebViews start loading? because I have a custom progress bar.

Comment: Add a webviewClient on your webview and monitor your website loaded completely. Hide the imageview once the website loaded completely